# MCMC beginner question at an example chain plot: Do I need more steps? How much burn-in do I need, if I can tell already?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, error, convergence

I am using the emcee python library to fit a model to data via MCMC. Below an example plot for the chain of one of my parameters. Here I ran 1000 steps with 100 walkers.

[image]

Now I have two beginner questions:

(1) Do I need more steps?
(2) Can I already tell how much burn-in would be appropriate, and if so, how much would that be?

I think I know the answers, but I am new to the matter and don't yet feel save with my judgement. Here is what I think:

to (1): I would say I do need more steps, as the walkers are still spreading out over the target distribution; i.e. the width of the sampled region is still increasing. This means that the outer region of the target distribution is still under-sampled, and this might end up in an underestimation of the errors.

to (2): If I am right with (1) then I don't know yet how much burn-in I need, since I have to wait until I see when the width of the sampled region stays approximately constant. The step when this starts to be the case then is the minimum burn-in which I need.

Am I right with this assessment?

For comparison, here the chain for another parameter, which already looks perfectly converged to my MCMC beginner's eye, and for which I might need a burn-in of about 100 steps, correct?

[image]

EDIT: This is a corner plot to the fit with 200 burn-in. The parameter rho0, for which (amongst others) the walkers still spread out corresponds to the bottom row.

[image]

Comment: The first graph certainly exhibits a lack of stationarity across replicates, hence would indicate that (much) more iterations are needed. The explosive pattern is actually a concern and I would check to see if the posterior is well defined.

Comment: Hi @Xi'an thanks for your advice! I will definitely see what happens if I double the steps. Could you please make more precise for me what you mean by "check if the posterior is well defined"? I edit a corner plot (with 200 burn-in) into my post in a minute.

Comment: The behaviour of the chains is coherent with a random walk behaviour indicative of a null-recurrent Markov chain associated with an infinite mass posterior (happening with improper priors)

Comment: Thanks again @Xi'an ! I had to read up a bit to understand your comment, but I think I do understand now what you mean. I am quite sure the prior is Gaussian, but I am not sure with what sigma. The center value should be quite close to that of the posterior, as I am using mock data here, and thus know roughly which parameters to expect. I will have to ask my colleagues who coded the fitting routine on details to the priors though. Meanwhile I will start a run with at least double the steps to see if the "explosive" pattern ends within this interval. Thanks again!